# AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Getting "attribute layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf not found" error while building.Please suggest.Tried implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3' in build.gradle but did not worked. Also, tried re-opening and cleaning the project and then rebuilding the project.But the same problem existing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/guitar1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="56dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <!-- Email Label -->
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <!-- Password Label -->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                    android:layout_width="328dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                    android:hint="Mobile No."
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="328dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:background="#ff1e56"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"

                android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
                />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="Login Instead!"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:textColor="#29c7ac"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is your error in logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you were wanting to put this EditText under parent, more precisely to be at the top where the constraint starts, right? The term start_toStartOf means the beginning (on the left) of something along with the beginning (on the left) of something else. So there is no way to put the left of something under something. You can place the top or bottom of something below or on top of something. In this case, you must use one of the following codes:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" (I think this is the most correct)
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
```

Read more in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

**EXTRA:**
You don't need too much ConstraintLayout to do this, you can do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- Email Label -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_name" />

        <!-- Password Label -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Mobile No."
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="#ff1e56"
            android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_mobile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login Instead!"
            android:textColor="#29c7ac"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_login" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```